# How to Identify the last executed time of a stored procedure in DB2?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I want to find when the stored procedure was last executed, so that I can delete the unused stored procedures. One way is to scan through the code and find out the list of used stored procedures and delete the unused one's, since the no of stored procedures is in thousands, I would like to know if there is an option in DB2 to find this easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what platform or version of DB2 you are using.

If you are running on DB2 for Linux/UNIX/Windows and are on V9.7 or later, you can look at the `LASTUSED` column in `SYSCAT.PACKAGES`, which can be joined to `SYSCAT.PROCEDURES` via `SYSCAT.ROUTINEDEP`:

```
select 
   proc.procschema
  ,proc.procname
  ,pkg.lastused
from 
   syscat.procedures proc
  ,syscat.routinedep rd
  ,syscat.packages   pkg
where 
   proc.specificname =  rd.routinename
   and rd.bname      =  pkg.pkgname
   and pkg.lastused  <> '01/01/0001'
order by 
   pkg.lastused desc;
```

If a procedure has never been executed, LASTUSED will have the value '01/01/0001'.  The query above filters these out.

Also, please note that you may want to filter on `PROCSCHEMA` so you're not seeing all of the system stored procedures...

Answer (score 0):

Without explicit logging or tracing, it is not possible to get this information for each and every Stored Procedure of our Database. However, we can get this detail along with many other relevant information for the stored procedure having it’s execution plan currently cached on the server by using - sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats It’s a system dynamic view that returns aggregate performance statistics for cached stored procedures.

This view returns one row for each cached stored procedure plan, and the lifetime of the row is as long as the stored procedure remains cached. When a stored procedure is removed from the cache, the corresponding row is eliminated from this view.

```
USE DBName    // replace with your DB name
GO  
SELECT   
 O.name,  
 PS.last_execution_time  
FROM   
 sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats PS   
INNER JOIN sys.objects O   
 ON O.[object_id] = PS.[object_id]   
GO
```

The above script will return the name of all the cached stored procedure of the current database with their last execution time.

For more details, please check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701.aspx)

In DB2, i think you can schedule a stored procedure to run at a particular time, at an interval, or when a specified event occurs. The administrative task scheduler manages these requests.

Procedure

To schedule execution of a stored procedure:

```
Add a task for the administrative task scheduler by using the ADMIN_TASK_ADD stored procedure. When you add your task, specify which stored procedure to run and when to run it. Use one of the following parameters or groups of parameters of ADMIN_TASK_ADD to control when the stored procedure is run:
```

interval - The stored procedure is to execute at the specified regular interval.
point-in-time - The stored procedure is to execute at the specified times.
trigger-task-name - The stored procedure is to execute when the specified task occurs.
trigger-task-name trigger-task-cond trigger-task-code - The stored procedure is to execute when the specified task and task result occur.

Optionally, you can also use one or more of the following parameters to control when the stored procedure runs:

begin-timestamp
    Earliest permitted execution time
end-timestamp
    Latest permitted execution time
max-invocations
    Maximum number of executions

When the specified time or event occurs for the stored procedure to run, the administrative task scheduler calls the stored procedure in DB2®.

1. Optional: After the task finishes execution, check the status by using the ADMIN_TASK_STATUS function. This function returns a table with one row that indicates the last execution status for each scheduled task. If the scheduled task is a stored procedure, the JOB_ID, MAXRC, COMPLETION_TYPE, SYSTEM_ABENDCD, and USER_ABENDCD fields contain null values. In the case of a DB2 error, the SQLCODE, SQLSTATE, SQLERRMC, and SQLERRP fields contain the information that DB2 returned from calling the stored procedure.

More information about ADMIN_TASK_STATUS [click here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.admin/src/tpc/db2z_schedulingstoredprocedure.htm)

Comment: That looks a lot like [tag:sql-server], and this question is tagged [tag:DB2].

Comment: This seems to be the command for SqlServer, Please let me know the table/view for DB2

Comment: k. In db2 how to schedule the execution time of SP, i will edit my answer.